# Order an array in a specific order

Tags: c#, arrays

I have this array of integers:-

```
int[] numbers = new int[] { 10, 20, 30, 40 };
```

I am trying to create an array which will have first element, last element, second element, second-last element and so on..

So, my resulting output will be:-

```
int[] result = {10,40,20,30};
```

This was my approach, in one loop start from first and go till the middle & in second loop start from last and get to the middle and select items accordingly, but I totally messed it up. Here is my attempted code:-

```
private static IEnumerable<int> OrderedArray(int[] numbers)
{
    bool takeFirst = true;
    if (takeFirst)
    {
        takeFirst = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length / 2; i++)
        {
            yield return numbers[i];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        takeFirst = true;
        for (int j = numbers.Length; j < numbers.Length / 2; j--)
        {
            yield return numbers[j];
        }
    }
}
```

Need Help.

Comment: Check for basics implementations of palindrome algorithm and try to adapt it to your desired output.

Comment: @blacai This... isn't really a palindrome though. How would that help?

Comment: Why do you have 2 separate cycles? It should be just one cycle which `yield` 2 items (by using indexes): (`0`, `n`), then (`1`, `n - 1`), then (`2`, `n - 2`)..

Comment: @J.Steen Here the requirement seems to be getting an ordered array with (i, i+counter, ... , i.lenght-counter, i.lenght-0) elements. ABCCBA = AA BB CC. Instead of just comparing them like in the palindrome algorith, he can take the elements he is checking each time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ok,

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> EndToEnd<T>(this IReadOnlyList<T> source)
    {
        var length = source.Count;        
        var limit = length / 2;
        for (var i = 0; i < limit; i++)
        {
           yield return source[i];
           yield return source[length - i - 1];
        }

        if (length % 2 > 0)
        {
            yield return source[limit];
        }
    }
}
```

Which you could use like this,

```
var result = numbers.EndToEnd().ToArray();
```

---

more optimally,

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> EndToEnd<T>(this IReadOnlyList<T> source)
    {
        var c = source.Count;
        for (int i = 0, f = 0, l = c - 1; i < c; i++, f++, l--)
        {
            yield return source[f];
            if (++i == c)
            {
               break;
            }

            yield return source[l];
        }
    }
}
```

no divide or modulus required.

Comment: Upvoted, but I would get rid of the "optimization" `if (length == 0) { yield break; }`. An empty list is not really special. Also, you could extend `IReadOnlyList<out T>` instead (covariance in `T` gained).

Comment: How is 0/2 ambiguous? If you had 0 then limit would be 0 and it would just skip everything from there wouldn't it?

Comment: @Chris had to check what 0 divided by something was.

Comment: @Jodrell: Always best to check everything. ;-)

Answer (score 5):

You might try this:

```
int[] result = numbers.Zip(numbers.Reverse(), (n1,n2) => new[] {n1, n2})
                      .SelectMany(x =>x)
                      .Take(numbers.Length)
                      .ToArray();
```

**Explanation:** This approach basically pairs up the elements of the original collection with the elements of its reverse ordered collection (using `Zip`). So you get a collection of pairs like [first, last], [second, second from last], etc.

It then flattens those collection of pairs into a single collection (using `SelectMany`). So the collection becomes [first, last, second, second from last,...].

Finally, we limit the number of elements to the length of the original array (n). Since we are iterating through twice as many elements (normal and reverse), it works out that iterating through `n` elements allow us to stop in the middle of the collection.

---

As a different approach, this is a modification on your existing method:

```
private static IEnumerable<int> OrderedArray(int[] numbers)
{
    var count = (numbers.Length + 1) / 2;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        yield return numbers[i];

        int reverseIdx = numbers.Length - 1 - i;
        if(i != reverseIdx)
            yield return numbers[reverseIdx];
    }
}
```

Comment: That could probably do with a little explanation for how it works. I worked it out but its not the most intuitive code...

Answer (score 3):

With a simple `for`;

```
int len = numbers.Length;
int[] result = new int[len];

for (int i = 0, f = 0, l = len - 1; i < len; f++, l--)
{
    result[i++] = numbers[f];

    if (f != l)
        result[i++] = numbers[l];
}
```

Comment: Thanks Alex, this is short :)

Comment: @Coder23, short but sweet.

Comment: @Jodrell - Yup short & sweet I meant :)

Answer (score 1):

Based on Selman22's now deleted answer:

```
int[] numbers = new int[] { 10, 20, 30, 40 };
int[] result = numbers
  .Select((x,idx) => idx % 2 == 0 
                     ? numbers[idx/2] 
                     : numbers[numbers.Length - 1 -idx/2])
  .ToArray();
  result.Dump();
```

(The last line is LinqPad's way of outputting the results)

Or in less LINQy form as suggested by Jeppe Stig Nielsen

```
var result = new int[numbers.Length]; 
for (var idx = 0; idx < result.Length; idx++) { 
    result[idx] = idx % 2 == 0 ? numbers[idx/2] : numbers[numbers.Length - 1 -idx/2]; 
}
```

The principle is that you have two sequences, one for even elements (in the result) and one for odd. The even numbers count the first half of the array and the odds count the second half from the back.

The only modification to Selman's code is adding the `/2` to the indexes to keep it counting one by one in the right half while the output index (which is what idx basically is in this case) counts on.

Comment: @Selman22: You should have seen my first attempt before yours inspired me! ;-) Hope you don't mind taking your answer. If you want to just modify yours with my change and undelete I'll get rid of mine...

Comment: no it's not a problem. I don't like to change my answer completely, after two attempts I stopped you nailed it :)

Comment: Why not: `var result = new int[numbers.Length]; for (var idx = 0; idx < result.Length; idx++) { result[idx] = idx % 2 == 0 
                     ? numbers[idx/2] 
                     : numbers[numbers.Length - 1 -idx/2]; }`. Or make two `for` loops. Starting with `numbers.Select` and not using `x` is ugly, in my opinion.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: You may well be right. This was a quick lazy modification of Selman's code. Many other people have now posted answers using for loops and generally doing it in better ways than this so I'll just leave this here as a proof of concept and let the upvotes demonstrate that this isn't necessarily the best way of doing things. ;-) For what its worth if you want to post that as an answer feel free. This question seems to be something of an answerfest! ;-)

Comment: Actually other answers don't really seem to do as you've suggested and on thinking about it I agree it is better. Edited into answer now.

Answer (score 0):

Came up with this

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<int> numbers = new List<int>() { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70};
        List<int> numbers2 = new List<int>();

        int counter1 = 0;
        int counter2 = numbers.Count - 1;
        int remainder = numbers.Count % 2 == 0 ? 1: 0;
        while (counter1-1 < counter2)
        {
            if (counter1 + counter2 % 2 == remainder)
            {
                numbers2.Add(numbers[counter1]);
                counter1++;
            }
            else
            {
                numbers2.Add(numbers[counter2]);
                counter2--;
            }
        }
        string s  = "";
        for(int a = 0; a< numbers2.Count;a++)
            s+=numbers2[a] + " ";
        Console.Write(s);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't produce the desired output (output is `10 70 60 50 40 30 20` desired output is `10 70 20 60 30 50 40`. Looks like the bug is that you need `(counter1+counter2)%2` since % is happening before the +.

Answer (score 0):

Came up with this

```
    public int[] OrderedArray(int[] numbers)
    {
        int[] final = new int[numbers.Length];
        var limit=numbers.Length;
        int last = numbers.Length - 1;
        var finalCounter = 0;

        for (int i = 0; finalCounter < numbers.Length; i++)
        {
            final[finalCounter] = numbers[i];
            final[((finalCounter + 1) >= limit ? limit - 1 : (finalCounter + 1))] = numbers[last];
            finalCounter += 2;
            last--;
        }

        return final;
    }
```

Comment: Looks promising, but will it really work if `numbers.Length` is an odd number?

Answer (score 0):

This late answer steals a lot from the existing answers!

The idea is to allocate the entire `result` array at once (since its length is known). Then fill out all even-indexed members first, from one end of `source`. And finally fill out odd-numbered entries from the back end of `source`.

```
public static TElement[] EndToEnd<TElement>(this IReadOnlyList<TElement> source)
{
  var count = source.Count;

  var result = new TElement[count];
  for (var i = 0; i < (count + 1) / 2; i++)
    result[2 * i] = source[i];
  for (var i = 1; i <= count / 2; i++)
    result[2 * i - 1] = source[count - i];

  return result;
}
```